# Set max session age with spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, embedded-tomcat

I would like to set the max session age, but I cannot see how to do this, I am already setting a session inactivity timeout of 15 minutes, but I also want to enforce a session max age of 12 hours, this would be regardless of whether the session is active.

Is this possible?

Comment: What servlet engine do you use? Tomcat? Jetty? Netty? The session timeout is part of the server configuration.

Comment: I am using embedded tomcat as the servlet engine.